# DNS records for DKIM email signing with split dns

Tags: dns, dkim

SO Gurus,
As part of our on-prem exchange upgrade we are planning on implementing DKIM signing. We have a bit of a unique setup and need some DNS help. Our internal domain is inside.maindomain.com and out external domain is maindomain.com.
Our internal DNS server is configured with a forward lookup zone for maindomain.com
Our ISP has DNS records pointing MX to our internal exchange server and also Autodiscover.
Everything is working as intended (has been for a long time) however there is confusion about where the DKIM TXT record with the key needs to be located. If we put the record out at our ISP then our internal lookup does not find it; if we put it internally on our DNS server then the mail server sees it and the outside world does not. Do we need to put it in both places? Or do we need some sort of A record pointing either out or in? Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Getting used to answering my own questions.... apparently the TXT record needs to exist both internally and externally. DKIM, DMARC and SPF all flowing correctly now.